# JavaScript byte logic

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

What does this JavaScript code mean?

```
flag &= ~CONST
```

Is it append, prepend, intersection or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will turn off whatever constant represents.

For example, lets look at a hypothetical example of code which would represent the state of  a window:

```
WS_HASBORDER           = 0x01;
WS_HASCLOSEBUTTON      = 0x02;
WS_HASMINIMIZEBUTTON   = 0x04;
WS_HASMAXIMIZEBUTTON   = 0x08;
WS_ISMAXIMIZED         = 0x10;
```

We could represent the "state" of the window by using
`windowState = WS_HASBORDER | WS_HASCLOSEBUTTON | ... etc`

now, lets say we want to "turn off" one of these states, well, thats what your example code does...
`windowState &= ~WS_HASBORDER`

Now what the above code does, is it gets the compliment [i guess you could call it the inverted bits] of whatever is to its right, WS_HASBORDER.

So.. WS_HASBORDER has one bit turned on, and everything else is turned off.  Its compliment has all bits turned on, except for the one bit that was turned off before.

Since I've represented the many constants as bytes, i'll just show you an example [not that javascript doesn't represent numbers as bytes, nor can you do so]

```
WS_HASBORDER           = 0x01; //0000 0001
WS_HASCLOSEBUTTON      = 0x02; //0000 0010
WS_HASMINIMIZEBUTTON   = 0x04; //0000 0100
WS_HASMAXIMIZEBUTTON   = 0x08; //0000 1000
WS_ISMAXIMIZED         = 0x10; //0001 0000
```

_ now for an example

```
windowState = WS_HASBORDER | WS_HASCLOSEBUTTON | WS_HASMINIMIZEBUTTON |
              WS_HASMAXIMIZEBUTTON | WS_ISMAXIMIZED;

     0000 0001
     0000 0010
     0000 0100
     0000 1000
and) 0001 0000
--------------
     0001 1111 = 0x1F
```

So... windowState gets the value 0x1F

windowState &= ~ WS_HASMAXIMIZEBUTTON

```
 WS_HASMAXIMIZEBUTTON: 0000 1000  
~WS_HASMAXIMIZEBUTTON: 1111 0111
```

..To finish our calculation

```
             windowState
&) ~WS_HASMAXIMIZEBUTTON

becomes
    0001 1111
&)  1111 0111
-------------
    0001 0111 = 0x07
```

Here are your resulting flags:
On:
WS_HASBORDER
WS_HASCLOSEBUTTON
WS_HASMINIMIZEBUTTON
WS_ISMAXIMIZED

Off:
WS_HASMAXIMIZEBUTTON

Hope that helps.  Back to procrastinating homework I go! haha.

Comment: I think "windowState = WS_HASBORDER & WS_HASCLOSEBUTTON & WS_HASMINIMIZEBUTTON & WS_HASMAXIMIZEBUTTON & WS_ISMAXIMIZED;" should be "windowState = WS_HASBORDER | WS_HASCLOSEBUTTON | WS_HASMINIMIZEBUTTON | WS_HASMAXIMIZEBUTTON | WS_ISMAXIMIZED;"

Answer (score 7):

Look at [Bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).

---

### & Operator

`&` puts 1 where both operands' bits are 1.

#### Example

```
10000001 & 00000001 = 00000001
```

---

### ~ Operator

`~` inverts the bits.

#### Example

```
~10000000 = 011111111;
```

---

`flag &= ~CONST` is short hand for `flag = flag & ~CONST;`.

You may have seen something similar, e.g. `number *= 10`.

Comment: @Jacob Relkin You'll never beat me voting me up! :P Thanks for stopping by :)

Comment: @alex, It's a friendly competition. If you give a nice answer, I'll vote it up. My rep can wait. It's about asking great questions and giving great answers. That's all.

Comment: @Jacob Relkin Of course! Just teasing :) It's Friday 4:40pm here!

Comment: @Nikolay Frantsev You mean what will `flag` contain after the line has executed? Follow the operators right to left. First, `CONST` will be the operand for `~`. Next, `flag` and `CONST` will be operands for `&`. Then, the result will be the value of `flag`.